# Change the order in which summary functions are printed by skim

Tags: r, printing, r-markdown, summary, skimr

I'm using `skimr`, and I added two summary functions (`iqr_na_rm` and `median_na_rm`) to the list of summary functions for the function `skim`. However, by default these new summary functions (called `skimmers` in `skimr` documentation) appear at the end of the table. Instead, I'd like  `median` and `iqr` to appear  after `mean` and `sd`.

The final goal is to show the results in a `.Rmd` report like this:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning = FALSE, 
                      message = FALSE,
                      echo    = FALSE)
```

## Test

```{r test, results = 'asis'}
library(skimr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

iqr_na_rm <- function(x) IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE)
median_na_rm <- function(x) median(x, na.rm = TRUE)

skim_with(numeric = list(p50 = NULL, median = median_na_rm, iqr = iqr_na_rm),
          integer = list(p50 = NULL, median = median_na_rm, iqr = iqr_na_rm))

msleep %>%
  group_by(vore) %>%
  skim(sleep_total) %>%
  kable()

```
````

Rendered HTML:

[image]

As you can see, `median` and `iqr` are printed and the end of the table, after the sparkline histogram. I'd like them to be printed after `sd` and before `p0`. Is it possible?

Comment: You probably can, but not without fiddling with source code. I think if you catch the ordering around [here](https://github.com/ropensci/skimr/blob/master/R/skim_print.R#L92) you could perhaps get things to work.

Comment: Did you try using append=FALSE and listing everything in the order you want?

Comment: Ciao @Elin ! No, I didn't try because I didn't know that was an option, but I was actually hoping for you or for Michael to chime in :-) can I suggest to add this option in a vignette? I think it could be useful. I might also try to make a PR. If you like the idea, I'll open a issue on the skimr repo. Of course, only if it's not there already - I could have missed it, or forgot about it.

Comment: That's a great idea  about the vignette.  We have to update all of them for V2, and we'll add that as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts in the `skim()` output. If you want to control the numeric part, you can use `skim_to_list` like this. It's also easier to export in another format.

```
msleep %>%
  group_by(vore) %>%
  skim_to_list(sleep_total)%>%
  .[["numeric"]]%>%
  dplyr::select(vore,variable,missing,complete,n,mean,sd,
                median,iqr,p0,p25,p75,p100,hist)

# A tibble: 5 x 14
  vore    variable    missing complete n     mean    sd     median iqr     p0    p25    p75     p100   hist    
* <chr>   <chr>       <chr>   <chr>    <chr> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>   
1 carni   sleep_total 0       19       19    10.38   4.67   10.4   " 6.75" 2.7   6.25   "13   " 19.4   ▃▇▂▇▆▃▂▃
2 herbi   sleep_total 0       32       32    " 9.51" 4.88   10.3   " 9.92" 1.9   "4.3 " 14.22   16.6   ▆▇▁▂▂▆▇▅
3 insecti sleep_total 0       5        5     14.94   5.92   18.1   "11.1 " 8.4   "8.6 " "19.7 " 19.9   ▇▁▁▁▁▁▃▇
4 omni    sleep_total 0       20       20    10.93   2.95   " 9.9" " 1.83" "8  " "9.1 " 10.93   "18  " ▆▇▂▁▁▁▁▂
5 NA      sleep_total 0       7        7     10.19   "3   " 10.6   " 3.5 " 5.4   8.65   12.15   13.7   ▃▃▁▁▃▇▁▇
```

**EDIT**

Adding `kable()` as requested in comment.

```
msleep %>%
  group_by(vore) %>%
  skim_to_list(sleep_total)%>%
  .[["numeric"]]%>%
  dplyr::select(vore,variable,missing,complete,n,mean,sd,median,iqr,p0,p25,p75,p100,hist)%>%
  kable()

|  vore   |  variable   | missing | complete | n  | mean  |  sd  | median | iqr  | p0  | p25  |  p75  | p100 |   hist   |
|---------|-------------|---------|----------|----|-------|------|--------|------|-----|------|-------|------|----------|
|  carni  | sleep_total |    0    |    19    | 19 | 10.38 | 4.67 |  10.4  | 6.75 | 2.7 | 6.25 |  13   | 19.4 | ▃▇▂▇▆▃▂▃ |
|  herbi  | sleep_total |    0    |    32    | 32 | 9.51  | 4.88 |  10.3  | 9.92 | 1.9 | 4.3  | 14.22 | 16.6 | ▆▇▁▂▂▆▇▅ |
| insecti | sleep_total |    0    |    5     | 5  | 14.94 | 5.92 |  18.1  | 11.1 | 8.4 | 8.6  | 19.7  | 19.9 | ▇▁▁▁▁▁▃▇ |
|  omni   | sleep_total |    0    |    20    | 20 | 10.93 | 2.95 |  9.9   | 1.83 |  8  | 9.1  | 10.93 |  18  | ▆▇▂▁▁▁▁▂ |
|   NA    | sleep_total |    0    |    7     | 7  | 10.19 |  3   |  10.6  | 3.5  | 5.4 | 8.65 | 12.15 | 13.7 | ▃▃▁▁▃▇▁▇ |
```

Comment: I still want to create a `kable` table though, because this is for a RMarkdown report. I should have clarified that in the question, but `.Rmd` files and `reprex` don't play nice together. I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: wow, I didn't think that just by adding `kable()` at the end of the pipe, your code would still work exactly the same way! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option that uses the append=FALSE option.

```
library(skimr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

iqr_na_rm <- function(x) IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE)
median_na_rm <- function(x) median(x, na.rm = TRUE)

my_skimmers <- list(n = length, missing = n_missing, complete = n_complete,
                     mean = mean.default, sd = purrr::partial(sd, na.rm = TRUE),
                     median = median_na_rm,  iqr = iqr_na_rm
                    )

skim_with(numeric = my_skimmers,
     integer = my_skimmers, append = FALSE)

msleep %>%
  group_by(vore) %>%
  skim(sleep_total) %>%
  kable()
```

I didn't put all the stats but you can look in the functions.R and stats.R files to see how the various statistics are defined.

Comment: This is nice! I still like the `skim_to_list()` option because it seems to me easier to combine with `select` in order to quickly change the list of skimmers in different parts of the code, but it's good to know that there's an official solution.